# react native intermittent crashing issue

Tags: react-native

I'm using React Native, but I'm having an issue where the app turns off when I reconnect after a few hours to the app.
The error log is as follows Does anyone know why and how to fix it?

react-native version: 0.63.3

Steps to reproduce

1. After installing the app, run it
2. Close the app
3. Remove completely from the background
4. After a few hours
5. When reconnecting, it immediately turns off as soon as the app runs

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Wrong state class, expecting View State but received class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$SavedState instead. This usually happens when two views of different types have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/0x1. Make sure other views do not use the same id.
```

Steps to reproduce
After installing the app, run it
Close the app
Remove completely from the background
After a few hours
When reconnecting, it immediately turns off as soon as the app runs.